# Getting list of states/events from a model that AASM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, aasm

I successfully integrated the most recent AASM gem into an application, using it for the creation of a wizard. In my case I have a model order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :billing_plan, :dependent => :destroy
  named_scope :with_user, ..... <snip>

  include AASM

  aasm_column :aasm_state
  aasm_initial_state :unauthenticated_user

  aasm_state :unauthenticated_user, :after_exit => [:set_state_completed]
  aasm_state : <snip>

  <and following the event definitions>

end
```

Now I would like to give an administrator the possibility to create his own graphs through the AASM states. Therefore I created two additional models called OrderFlow and Transition where there order_flow has many transitions and order belongs_to order_flow.

No problem so far. Now I would like to give my admin the possibility to dynamically add existing transitions / events to an order_flow graph.

The problem now is, that I do not find any possibility to get a list of all events / transitions out of my order model. aasm_states_for_select seems to be the correct candidate, but I cannot call it on my order model.

Can anyone help?

Thx in advance. 
J.

Answer (score 9):

With version `3.0.18`, you can should use `ClassName.aasm.states`

Comment: `ClassName.aasm.states.map(&:name)` will get you an Array of Symbols, which may be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how OrderFlow works with Order and Transitions, but I assumed you just included that to explain your scenario better.

ClassName.aasm_states_for_select gives you a list of states that is declared in the model.

Comment: That's deprecated now. Use `ClassName.aasm.states_for_select`.

Answer (score 2):

For **events** in `3.1.1` I used `Model.aasm.events.keys` to get an array of event name symbols. In recent versions `.map(&:name)` won't do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

also, not 100% sure what you're asking for, but if you want all the states and events declared for your model you could get those by calling Order.aasm_states and Order.aasm_events respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In version 5.4.0 this seems to now be an array, so we are back to

```
Model.aasm.events.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant Ruby syntax can be used, as in this example in IRB below.  You get all the allowable states in an array of symbols.

```
1.9.3-p0 :011 > ApprovalRequest.aasm_states.map(&:name)
```

=> [:created, :submitted, :rejected, :approved]